# Why is $E[X1_A]=0$ if $P(A)=0$?

Tags: probability-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I know this is trivial and intuitive, but I'm not able to convince myself rigorously. If $P(A)=0$, why is it true that $E(X1_A)=0$?

Every book discards it out as an obvious fact. I tried to prove it using the simple functions definition of Lebesgue integration.

Comment: In the discrete case, we simply add a finite number of $0$'s. In the continous case, we have an integral over a function, which is $0$ everywhere, where it has to be considered. So, what is the problem ?

Comment: You are right. But what if $X$ takes arbitrarily large values? I was wondering where the assumption $X\in L^1$ comes into play here.

Comment: If $A$ has measure zero, you can modify $X$ on $A$ to be zero without changing its integral. Basically, all you're showing is that if you integrate over a set of measure zero, you get zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Proposition:** Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be a measure space, $f:\Omega\to [0,\infty)$ a measurable function and $A$ a measurable set with $P(A)=0$. Then,
>   $$\int_AfdP=0.$$

**Proof:** First, suppose $s=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\chi_{A_i}$ is a simple measurable function (i.e. the range of $s$ is a finite set $\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}$, and $A_i=s^{-1}(a_i)\in\mathcal{F}$). Then, by definition
$$\int_AsdP=\sum_{i=1}^na_iP(A_i\cap A)\leq\sum_{i=1}^na_iP(A)=0.$$
Now, it is a theorem that any measurable function $f:\Omega\to[0,\infty)$ is the pointwise limit of a non-decreasing sequence $s_n$ of simple measurable function. Hence, by Lebesgue monotone convergence theorem,
$$\int_A fdP=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_As_ndP=\lim_{n\to\infty}0=0.$$

Comment: My question is why $\int_A h(x)dx=0$ if $P(A)=0$?

Comment: @elexhobby If I start over and explain you why $\int_A fd\mu=0$ if $\mu(A)=0$, where $\mu$ is any measure and $f$ any measurable function, would that answer your question?

Comment: I think so. Because $E(X1_A)=\int_A X\,dP + \int_{A^c} 0\,dP = \int_A X\,dP$. So if you can explain why $\int_A X\,dP=0$, I'll appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

Let's prove it for a nonnegative $X$.

A stepfunction $0\leq f\leq X1_A$ can be written as $c_1\times 1_{B_1}+\cdots+c_n\times 1_{B_n}$ with $c_i>0$. This leads to $B_i\subseteq A$ so that $0\leq P(B_i)\leq P(A)=0$.

So $\int fdP=c_1\times P(B_1)+\cdots+c_n\times P(B_n)=0$.

Then $\mathbb EX1_A=0$ as supremum of these values.